# virtualbox get access winscp access from host (vista) to guest (ubuntu)

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, host, winscp

what worked fine is
http://kdl.nobugware.com/post/2009/02/17/virtualbox-nat-ssh-guest/
so that i can connect to guest system using ssh with putty

but winscp does not work? what i still have to install? ssh was installed on ubuntu apt-get, but what else... does winscp from vista need more ports? and if how to manage this?!

Comment: What connection parameters are you giving winscp?  You sure that the port is correct?

Comment: i simply connect to the same port as with putty: 2222 on the forwarded localhost... using scp or sftp all brings both no connection :-S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost on the session in winscp , different than putty but it works, why? I dont know :P ...